# MySQL(5.1.61): Phpymyadmin ( 3.3.7) trying to import sql file of about 500kb

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

fails, saying:

```
SELECT `comment`
FROM `phpmyadmin`.`pma_column_info`
WHERE db_name = '`my_database`'
AND table_name = ''
AND column_name = '(db_comment)'

MySQL said: Documentation
#1100 - Table 'pma_column_info' was not locked with LOCK TABLES
```

why? How can I change this?

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215379/importing-sql-file-using-phpmyadmin-in-easy-php

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [link](http://amir-shenodua.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/error-while-importing-db-in-mysql.html) , which describes how to troubleshoot the issue. I hope you need to make some changes to config.inc.php in phpadmin directory.