# error in locking 'pma__column_info' after change in config.inc.php

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I need to import some big sql text files (120 and 300 MB) to a local database via phpmyadmin. I succeeded at the smaller dbs, around 8 and 18 MB, but got several time-outs on the next one (120 MB).

Following a suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21641325/1086511), I inserted "$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;" in two different places in config.inc.php, and now I got this error:

```
SQL query: DocumentationEdit Edit

SELECT `comment`
FROM `phpmyadmin`.`pma__column_info`
WHERE db_name = 'bot4b'
AND table_name = ''
AND column_name = '(db_comment)'

MySQL said: Documentation
#1100 - Table 'pma__column_info' was not locked with LOCK TABLES
```

I commented out the "$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;", but the error persists. I restarted apache and even rebooted.

After the boot, I created a new database, and tried to reimport the smaller one (8 MB), with the same error.

I think it's not a user/password problem, and I'm afraid to try the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18226505/1086511) without knowing what I'm doing. I prefer to understand what's happening than just applying blind fixes that could ruin the system even more. (Btw, my 'controluser' and 'controlpass' are uncommented, and set to local variables $dbuser and $dbpass as default.)

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, Apache 2.4.7 (Ubuntu), MySQL 14.14 and PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.11 (cli)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have  you tried using the command line for importing?

Comment: not yet, thanks for the idea.

Comment: I believe phpMyadmin has limitations due to the web interface  (I remember running into this some time ago), and I had to use the command line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using MySQL command line tools to do this, using web interface takes long and really you'll run into a lot of problems.

You could use:

```
mysql -p -u user_name database_name < file.sql
```

or

```
mysqlimport [options] db_name textfile1
```

Comment: OK, that works. But what exactly happened to phpmyadmin, that was able to import my 8MB database, and now is not?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this.

Basically add some php config to the phpmyadmin alias configuration that will increase various php parameters just while you are using phpMyAdmin.

I am not ubuntu expert but I think the alias is defined in `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf`

If you add these parameters to the `<Directory.... </Directory>`

```
<Directory ......>

  . . .

  . . . 
  php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
  php_admin_value post_max_size 128M
  php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
  php_admin_value max_input_time 360
</Directory>
```